# Why does my await lambda.invoke function invoke lambda multiple times?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, promise, aws-lambda, async-await

**Currently**

I have a **lambdaX** that invokes another **lambdaY**.

Lambda X:

```js
"use strict";

const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.region = 'ap-southeast-2';
var lambda = new AWS.Lambda();

exports.handler = async (event) => {

  //the final return
  var dataToSave = []

  //data to be added to array
  let returnLoad;

  var params = {
    FunctionName: 'lambdaY', // the lambda function we are going to invoke
    InvocationType: 'RequestResponse',
    LogType: 'Tail', //Set to Tail to include the execution log in the response.
  };

  try {
    await lambda.invoke(params, function(err, data) {
      if (err) {
        console.log("Error");
        console.log(err, err.stack);
      } else {
        console.log("Success");
        console.log(data);
        returnLoad = data.Payload;
      }
    }).promise();

    dataToSave.push(returnLoad);

  } catch (err) {
      console.log('some error occurred...');
  }

  const response = {
      statusCode: 200,
      body: JSON.stringify(dataToSave)
  };
  return response;
}
```

Lambda Y:

```js
exports.handler = async (event) => {
    const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify('Hello from Lambda!'),
    };
    return response;
};
```

**Problem**

For some reason **lambdaY** invokes 2+ times whenever I invoke **lambdaX**. Note, **lambdaX** gets the correct response back, but I want to avoid unnecessarily invoking **lambdaY** multiple times.

What do I need to change in my code? (or lambda configuration)

**Logs:**

*Note: 2 logs of lambdaY being invoked at exactly the same time.*

[image]

*Note: LambdaX results are healthy and as expected. There isn't a duplicate log.*

[image]

Comment: Have you confirmed that lambdaY is being initiated by lambdaX both times? For example the event that's triggering lambdaX might also be triggering lambdaY due to a configuration issue. Maybe try logging the payload of lambdaY to confirm it's coming from lambdaX.

Comment: Additionally, have you check the logs to ensure lambdaX is only being triggered once?

Comment: @jpetty, yes, the logs of lambdaX show it is only being triggered once, and logs of lambdaY show payload coming from X (when I have included a payload to test that question)

Comment: Thanks @Wronski, typically seeing duplicate lambda invocations would be caused by [failure retries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57565650/calling-a-lambda-function-once-its-executed-twice). lambdaY might be failing causing lambdaX to retry. What's in the logs of lambdaX? Does it get a successful response back from lambdaY?

Comment: @jpetty, I have added logs for lambdaX. They were as expected and showing no errors.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your code is misusing the AWS SDK. Specifically, it is using *both* the callback and promise features simultaneously. It should use one or the other, but not both.

I would change it to use just the promise (and obviously add some error handling to this):

```
const data = await lambda.invoke(params).promise();
const returnLoad = data.Payload;
```

The reason that `lambda.invoke(params, callback).promise()` sends 2 requests is as follows:

1. within the AWS SDK generally, a call to `service.action(params)` returns an AWSRequest object on which you have to call `.send()` for the API request to actually be sent
2. a call to `service.action(params, callback)` executes the following code: `if (callback) request.send(callback)`, so the presence of the callback function sends the API request
3. the `.promise()` method's code "sends the request and returns a promise", so it *also* sends the API request

And that's why the API call happens twice if callback and promise() are both present.