# Lambda long running task gets executed two times with no errors

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda

I am calling a lambda via aws-sdk with explicit `RequestResponse`

```
const Lambda = require("aws-sdk/clients/lambda");
const lambda = new Lambda({region: "region"});

const params = {
  FunctionName: "myFunctionArn",
  InvocationType: "RequestResponse",
  Payload: JSON.stringify({
    //... my payload
  })
};

lambda.invoke(params).promise().then(data => {
  console.log(data);
});
```

It is a **long running task >~5 minutes** and my timeout is set to **10 minutes**. I download an mp3, compress it, save it to S3 and then return the url to the client.
There are no errors in cloudwatch and the process goes smoothly, the mp3 is store with lower quality to S3, however the function gets executed two times.

If the mp3 file is small enough (~8 MB) there is only one execution, however if it is a big file (~100MB) it will get executed two times and of course the function will timeout. I am using the **/tmp** folder to store the file temporarily, I will as well remove them after the mp3 has been safely stored in S3 
I have scattered my function with logging and there is absolutely no sign of errors and this is happening every single time, not sporadically.

Those are my cloudwatch logs
[image]

Thanks

EDIT_1: I have tried by adding some options to the lambda client

```
const Lambda = require("aws-sdk/clients/lambda");
const lambda = new Lambda({
  region: "ap-southeast-1",
  httpOptions: { timeout: 10 * 60 * 1000, connectTimeout: 10 * 60 * 1000 }
});
```

But looks like nothing has changed

EDIT_2: seems like now this is happening also for short running tasks and is completely random. I am at loss here I really don't know what to do

Comment: Check out the first answer on this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57565650/calling-a-lambda-function-once-its-executed-twice

Comment: Thanks, but I have already checked all the answers and in my case I have no errors and my execution is synchronous.

Comment: hard to say anything without looking at your lambda function code.

Comment: Have you logged around the code that invokes the Lambda just to rule out a double execution? That way you can know for sure this is happening on the AWS side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending countless hours through debugging, I just discovered that the cause of this weird behavior was because the function was going out of memory.
Incredibly enough nothing showed up on Cloudwatch.

Answer (score 1):

Setting maxRetries to 0 in the SDK config params will turn off retries being invoked by the SDK itself.

```
const Lambda = require("aws-sdk/clients/lambda");
const lambda = new Lambda({
  maxRetries: 0,
  region: "ap-southeast-1",
  httpOptions: { timeout: 10 * 60 * 1000, connectTimeout: 10 * 60 * 1000 }
});
```

Comment: I figured out that there was an options like that and tried, however it still does get invoked twice. Anyway one up-vote for you, it might help others